# How to escape single quote in sparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to pySpark and SQL. I am working on below query;

```
sqlContext.sql("Select Crime_type, substring(Location,11,100) as Location_where_crime_happened, count(*) as Count\
                            From street_SQLTB\
                            where LSOA_name = 'City of London 001F' and \
                            group by Location_where_crime_happened, Crime_type\
                            having Location_where_crime_happened = 'Alderman'S Walk'")
```

I am struggling in dealing with single quote. I need to apply filter on **Alderman'S Walk**.  It could be easy one but I am unable to figure out.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: "The escape character is '\'. If an escape character precedes a special symbol or another escape character, the following character is matched literally. It is invalid to escape any other character." (source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html )

Comment: sqlContext.sql("Select Crime_type, substring(Location,11,100) as Location_where_crime_happened, count(*) as Count\
                            From street_SQLTB\
                            where LSOA_name = 'City of London 001F' and \
                            group by Location_where_crime_happened, Crime_type\
                            having Location_where_crime_happened = 'Alderman\'\S Walk'")

This is how I am trying to escape the character but it isn't working.

Comment: It is giving me below error:

ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'and' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 210)\n\n== SQL ==\nSelect Crime_type, substring(Location,11,100) as Location_where_crime_happened, count(*) as Count                            From street_SQLTB                            where LSOA_name = 'City of London 001F' and                             group by Location_where_crime_happened, Crime_type                            having Location_where_crime_happened = 'Alderman'\\S Walk'\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^\n"

Comment: While you can do [Code Formating in Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77485/code-formating-in-comments/77490#77490), most of the times it's better to [edit] the question, and add the info to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
simpleData = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000), \
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000), \
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000), \
    ("Maria","Alderman'S Walk","CA",90000,24,23000) \
  ]
columns= ["employee_name","department","state","salary","age","bonus"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('temp') 

df = sqlContext.sql("""select * from temp where department = "Alderman'S Walk" """)
display(df)
```

or

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from temp where department = 'Alderman\\'S Walk' ")
display(df)
```

Filtered output:
[image]